# Does changing main resource amount change the corresponding resource amount for Caves and Ruins?

Tags: dont-starve

Because Caves and Ruins basically have reskins of the main world resources (rocks, grass, twig bushes, etc), I figured they might also change in number when changing the amount of normal (main map) resources generated in landgen options when you create a new world. Is that so?

Comment: This is a great question, but I think you will probably be able to get a better answer on the Klei Forum.  The people who populate that site tend to be developers who are writing mods, etc. for the game.  Anytime I have had a question of this nature, I've found they were a good resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Klei Forum:  It only affects the resources above ground in Sandbox mode (*i.e.* not Adventure Mode, not in caves).

[There wasn't much of a discussion, but you can read it here.](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/31124-does-changing-any-of-the-world-resources-affect-the-caves-or-other-worlds/)